# Fractions and decimals in different bases

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

How exactly would I add fractions of different bases?

For example: $ (\frac 23)_8 + (\frac 57)_8$

and is their any difference to that of adding those same numbers but in decimal form base 8?

Comment: It's similar.  Put them over a common deniminator.  $\frac 23*\frac 77 =\frac {16_8}{25_8} $ and $\frac 57*\frac 33 =\frac {17_8}{25_8} $ so the sum is $\frac {35_8}{25_8}=1\frac {10}{25}_8$ (which IS in lowest terms BTW) and is $1\frac 8 {21}_{10} $.

Comment: Is it? In base 10 it's (14+15)/21 = 29/21 = 1 and 8/21.  In base 8 it's (16+17)/25 = 35/25 = 1 and 10/25.  I really think I am correct, this time. $16_8 + 17_8 = (8+6)+(8+7)= 2*8 +(7+6) =2*8+(8+5)=3*8 +5 =35_8$.

Comment: You *can* simply add them in base 10 and convert;  2/3 +5/7 = 29/21 and convert to base 8; 35/25-- but that's avoiding the issue.  If bases are arbitrary, and they are, one should be able to do them directly in base 8.  And to do that we note:2x7=16. 5x3=17.  3x7=25.  And 16+17=35.  And 35 is prime.  And the prime factors of 25 are 3 and 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways to do this.

The easy but half assed way.

$2,3,5,7$ in base $8$ are the same in base $10$.  So $\frac 23_{10}=\frac 23_8$ and $\frac 57_{10}=\frac 57_8$.

So $\frac 23 + \frac 57 = \frac {29_{10}}{21_{10}}=\frac{35_8}{25_8}=\frac {35}{25}_8$.

Now the "real" way (where we work in base 8 directly without constantly translating back and forth from base 10.

$\frac 23 + \frac 57 = \frac {2*7}{3*7}+\frac {5*3}{7*3}=\frac {2*7+5*3}{3*7}=\frac {(1*8+6)+(1*8+7)=2*8+(6+7)=2*8+(1*8+5)=3*8+5}{2*8+5}=\frac {35_8}{25_8}=\frac {35}{25}_8$.

Answer (score 0):

first we should make the denominator same to add both of them 
therefore (2*7/3*7)8=(14/21)8  ----1
          (5*3/7*3)8=(15/21)8   ----2
now we can equation 1 and 2 
since the denominator and the base both are same
therefore we get 
(29/21)8 is the answer.

Comment: Um, that's base 10.  Not base 8. 2x7 doesn't equal 14, 3x7 doesn't equal 21. 5x3 doesn't equal 15, and 14 + 15 doesn't equal 29.  In base 8 the answer is 35/25.  Because 29 is 35_8 and 21 is 21_8.

Comment: $\frac {2*7}{3*7}_8=\frac {8+6}{2*8+5}=\frac {15}{25}_8$.  Meanwhile $\frac {5*3}{7*3}_8=\frac{8+7}{2*8+5}=\frac {17}{25}_8$.  And finally $16_8+17_8=(8+6)+(8+7)=2*8+(7+6)=2*8+(8+5)=3*8+5=35_8$.  So the sum is $\frac {35}{25}_8$.